# when I export a pptx file as a png file from google drive,how can I access al slides,no just the first slide

Tags: php, powerpoint, google-drive-api

the question is when I use API to access the pptx file in Google drive, I can only export the first slide of this file, but when I use viewer to download slide as png, I can download each single slide. So there is a way to access each slide in a pptx file on Google drive, can we know the way?

Answer (score 0):

Google list the [supported export formats for Google Docs](http://edutraining.googleapps.com/Training-Home/module-4-docs/chapter-1/3-2).  .PNG is not listed as a supported export format for presentations, so I'm not surprised that it doesn't work properly.   I does say that you can export to Microsoft PowerPoint (.ppt), PDF (.pdf), or Text (.txt).

Comment: I already fixed this problem,please refer to here. [Changbaotu.com](http://changbaotu.com)

Comment: it is a Chinese encode website,pls aware the before you try to view.